# Why do we still consider a doping concentration in undoped MOSFET devices?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

I am studying cryogenic behaviour of MOSFET devices especially the evolution of threshold voltage with temperature.
I mostly measure **FinFET** and **FDSOI** devices, all which have supposedly **undoped** channel.

Yet in most paper a small doping concentration is still given (small around 10^15): [Example from arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09013). Moreover, in threshold voltage cryogenic models the main contribution to the temperature evolution is given by the evolution of the Fermi potential which always include dopant freezout in calculation.
[Example](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09911)

So my question: Why do we still consider a doping concentration in intrinsic MOSFET devices?

Comment: If made in bulk silicon, all 150mm and larger wafers are Czochralski grown and B doped. The CZ growth is for carbon concentration making them strong enough, and the doping is intentional to set them at a specified doping type and level rather than having wafers come out all over the place in level and type.